# Use range as variable instead of variant

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have `t` and `u` as range variables instead of variant in the function THours, where the latter is built up by the function Hours?

```
Public Function Hours(x As Range, y As Range, w As Range) As Double

Dim n As Integer
Dim z As Double


For n = 1 To y.Columns.count

    If (y.Cells(1, n) > 0) And (y.Cells(1, n) <> "") Then
        z = z + (w.Cells(1, n) * x.Cells(1, n) / y.Cells(1, n))
    End If


Next n

Hours = z
End Function

Public Function THours(t As Variant, u As Variant, w As Variant) As Double
 Dim z As Double
 Dim r As String
 Dim Ressource As Variant

    z = 0
    ' this is just an array
    Ressource = get_sheet_names()

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = LBound(Ressource) To UBound(Ressource)
           r = Ressource(i)
           z = z + Hours(.Sheets(r).Range(t), .Sheets(r).Range(u), .Sheets(r).Range(w))
        Next i
    End With

    THours = z
End Function
```

I am grateful for every answer.

Thanks

Comment: "where the latter is built up by the function Hours"... By "latter are you referring to `u` or `THours`? Can you define what you mean by "built up by"? Of course arrays can be passed to functions but it's unclear to me exactly what you want. I have questions like... Are these functions independent? Are they called from code or as a worksheet function? Is the range a selection by the user or some range reference aggregated in the code? What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: hi Mark, no the first function goes through one sheet and  has three columns as variables(range) and it is a worksheet function which gives in some sense the sum of hours of one person. the second function Thours( total hours) loops over all worksheet names of the persons which are generated by an array by the "get_sheet_names()" function (i didnt wrote the code of it here) and uses the Hours function before. My problem ist that for the code of Thours i use t and u as variant variables, but i wanna have range variables. I tried to use Hours(.Sheets(r).t,.Sheets(r).u,..). But this does not work

Comment: Well a worksheet function that has to iterate through all worksheets shouldn't take ranges because those range references change as you move through the sheets. Unless of course you want to extract the address from the range references and use that going forward but that is only good if you use something like C:F and not C2:F50 because not all sheets have same number of rows (I'm guessing). Why not just feed as parameters what column numbers you want to sum up??

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for, but it is hard to tell based on the little information you have provided.

Also, I'm confused by your question given that in the `Hours` function it appears the code is doing what you want to do in the `THours` function.

```
Public Function Hours(x As Range, y As Range, w As Range) As Double
    Dim n                       As Integer
    Dim z                       As Double

    For n = 1 To y.Columns.Count
        If (y.Cells(1, n) > 0) And (y.Cells(1, n) <> "") Then
            z = z + (w.Cells(1, n) * x.Cells(1, n) / y.Cells(1, n))
        End If
    Next n

    Hours = z
End Function

Public Function THours(t As Range, u As Range, w As Range) As Double
    Dim z                       As Double
    Dim Ressource               As Variant

    z = 0
    ' this is just an array
    Ressource = get_sheet_names()

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = LBound(Ressource) To UBound(Ressource)
            r = Ressource(i)
            z = z + Hours(t.Value, u.Value, w.Value)
        Next i
    End With

    THours = z
End Function
```